when should I NOT use hardware_destructive_interference_size with std::atomic
hardware_destructive_interference_size is used to prevent false sharing. cppreference has an example that tries to keep some other data together with the std::atomic:
// from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size
struct together
{
    std::atomic<int> dog;
    int puppy;
};

Question: In most cases, I think we would want together to have an alignment of hardware_destructive_interference_size and in the usual case, we would want std::atomic to have an alignment of hardware_destructive_interference_size, so as to prevent false sharing. When is this not the case?

The purpose of the full example (you only showed part of it) is that you want to make sure that if you access the atomic, you have already loaded the cache line containing puppy. This is constructive interference, not destructive interference.

It could make sense if you know write will be infrequent and compactness is more important than the performance of not being cache aligned. For example, maybe you have something like this:
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t isPrimeResultsSize = 100'000'000;
    constexpr size_t threadCount = 16;
    constexpr size_t primesPerThread = isPrimeResultsSize / threadCount;
    std::atomic<char>*const isPrimeResults = new std::atomic<char>[isPrimeResultsSize]();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    auto isPrimeSlow = [](size_t n)
    {
        if (n < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (size_t div = 2; div < n / 2; div++)
        {
            if (n % div == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {
        auto toRun = [=, &isPrimeSlow]()
        {
            const size_t start = i * primesPerThread;
            const size_t end = i == threadCount-1 ?
                isPrimeResultsSize :
                start + primesPerThread;
            for (size_t n = start; n < end; n++)
            {
                isPrimeResults[n].store(isPrimeSlow(n) ? 2 : 1,
                    std::memory_order_release);
            }
        };

        threads.emplace_back(toRun);
    }

    bool* reportedResult = new bool[isPrimeResultsSize]();
    bool foundAll{false};
    while (!foundAll)
    {
        foundAll = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < isPrimeResultsSize; i++)
        {
            if (reportedResult[i]) continue;
            char result = isPrimeResults[i].load(std::memory_order_acquire);
            if (!result)
            {
                foundAll = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (result == 2) std::printf("%zu is prime!\n", i);
            reportedResult[i] = true;
        }
    }

    delete[] reportedResult;
    delete[] isPrimeResults;

    return 0;
}

In my example, the number of atomics is really huge and on an amd64 platform, hardware_destructive_interference_size is a whopping 64 bytes. In fact, if you know you have a bunch of related atomics, it might be a good idea to keep things close together so that way you aren't invalidating multiple cache lines all at once. You could even be more extreme than the example and use bitsets instead of one byte per item (1 bit to mark item as done and another for the result).
